# Radio button text not aligned properly

Tags: html, css

So i am trying to add radio button on my survey form and the button and the text is completly in different positions so here is a picture of how it looks --> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKUQl.png)

i tried display: inline; but still nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

The below code will work as you expected. Just add necessary attributes like `name` and `for`.

```html
 <p>Would you recommend this survey to your friend:</p>
 <input type="radio" name="test" value="yes">
 <label for="test">Yes</label><br>
```

Comment: tried it nothing changed

Comment: Can you provide your code? Because the above code works fine in the compiler as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

According to the picture, your input tag width is 100%, that's why you are facing this issue. Add class inside input and use this CSS your problem has been fixed.

```
<style>
.inline-radio{width: auto;}
</style>

**HTML**
<p>Would you recommend this survey to your friend:</p>
<input type="radio" name="test" value="yes" class="inline-radio" >
<label for="test">Yes</label>
```